# Intellij idea Plugin Error(Problems found loading plugins:)

Tags: intellij-idea, plugins

when I start idea,there is a problem like this:

```
enter code here17:59    Plugin Error
    Problems found loading plugins:
    Plugin "Persistence Frameworks Support" was not loaded: required plugin "Database Tools and SQL" is disabled.
    Plugin "GlassFish Integration" was not loaded: required plugin "Java EE: EJB, JPA, Servlets" is disabled.
    Plugin "JBoss Integration" was not loaded: required plugin "Java EE: EJB, JPA, Servlets" is disabled.
    Plugin "JSR45 Integration" was not loaded: required plugin "Java EE: EJB, JPA, Servlets" is disabled.
    Plugin "Jetty Integration" was not loaded: required plugin "Java EE: EJB, JPA, Servlets" is disabled.
    Plugin "Resin Integration" was not loaded: required plugin "Java EE: EJB, JPA, Servlets" is disabled.
    Plugin "Tomcat and TomEE Integration" was not loaded: required plugin "Java EE: EJB, JPA, Servlets" is disabled.
    Plugin "CloudBees integration" was not loaded: required plugin "Java EE: EJB, JPA, Servlets" is disabled.
    Plugin "Geronimo Integration" was not loaded: required plugin "Java EE: EJB, JPA, Servlets" is dis... (show balloon)
```

i can't enable it,it's red.

[image]

what need i do to slove this problem?

Comment: Have you tried reading the message you posted here? It says quite clearly  why it is displayed.

Comment: it said "*** is disabled.",but i don't known why ,and i don't known how to slove it,can you help me ?

Comment: Open Settings | Plugns and enable it.

Comment: i tried ，but it can't by enabled. you can see the picture in my question

Comment: Delete `disabled_plugins.txt` file from the [config directory](https://intellij-support.jetbrains.com/hc/articles/206544519).

Answer (score 11):

This steps caN help in fixing the issues. This were actually provided in the intellij support site

1. Navigate to settings -> plugins
2. Uncheck all the plugins that were giving the errors (they were red in my list) -> apply changes -> close settings
3. IntelliJ might ask you to restart (do it)
4. Navigate back to plugins. -> Enable missing plugin (for me it was Database Tools and SQL)
5. Apply and restart as directed.
6. Navigate to plugins and reenable the (JAVA EE etc ) plugins as required.

Please follow this [Intellij](https://intellij-support.jetbrains.com/hc/en-us/community/posts/205989564-Problems-found-loading-plugins-in-2016-3) link if you face any issues after following the above steps

Comment: I'm not the owner of this question. just found this when I was searching :)

Comment: @RoHaN No Worries :)

Answer (score 3):

Delete `disabled_plugins.txt` file from the config directory as @CrazyCoder stated above

Answer (score -1):

Click 'show balloon' and click 'Enable Database Tools and SQL'.